# How to run a Java Project after converting database from ms access to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have converted a java project ms access database to mysql and run it from localhost wamp server. Now I have connected the database to Netbeans java project. But I am not able to run the project. It is saying build failed. Is there any particular reason it is not working? Here's the code for the connection that I have made.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Settings {
public static Dimension getScreenSize(){
    Dimension d=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    return d;   
}//getScreenSize() closed

public static Connection getDBConnection(){
    Connection con;
    try{
        Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","root","root");
        return con;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return null;
    }
}
}//class closed
```

I have made changes on other .java files that try to connect to database. For eg the login.java file has connection which I have changed:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == btnLogin) {
        try {
            Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","root","root");
```

Please suggest me.

The exception I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
at Login.<init>(Login.java:36)
at Login.main(Login.java:90)
C:\Users\MyPc\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: You are swallowing exceptions, at minimum log the exception (or use `ex.printStackTrace`).

Answer (score 0):

the "java.sql.Driver" is the interface for drivers and as such not an implementation. You need to load the driver for mysql

try and change

```
java.sql.Driver
```

to

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

**And:** Don't suppress your Exception like that:

```
}catch(Exception ex){
    return null;
}
```

You never know what goes wrong. At least print the exception there:

```
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Changed this with no luck.

Comment: Using `Class.forName` has not been necessary since at least 2006 (assuming the driver is JDBC 4 compliant).

Comment: Did you print the exception? What Exception is thrown?

Comment: Yes I did. I have edited the question and mentioned the exception at the end of my question.

Comment: Your exception says there is an error which is not related to mysql but to swing. Maybe investigate that and open a new question if necessary.